# How to rotate an object?

Tags: python, scripting, transforms

I want to rotate object in blender, for which I am using following operations.

```
ob = bpy.context.active_object
ob.rotation_euler = (x,y,z)
```

It is working well. Now if reaped the this definition for same object, it doesn't consider the last updated orientation. It considers the original orientation.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried  ob.rotation_euler.rotate( Euler( (x, y, z) ) ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You are setting the rotation.**

The code in question you are setting the Euler rotation.  The resulting value will always be `(x, y, z)`

Instead recommend make a transform (rotation) matrix. Python console example. x, y, and z are 30, 45 and 60 degrees respectively.

```
>>> x, y, z = (radians(30), radians(45), radians(60))
>>> Euler((x, y, z))
Euler((0.5235987901687622, 0.7853981852531433, 1.0471975803375244), 'XYZ')
```

The context object, has Euler rotation set to zero.

```
>>> ob = C.object
>>> ob.rotation_euler
Euler((0.0, -0.0, 0.0), 'XYZ')
```

Create a transform matrix from our Euler. Make it 4x4 so we can multiply it by the 4x4 object matrix.  Notice after the first multiplication we get the result as above.

```
>>> R = Euler((x, y, z)).to_matrix().to_4x4()
>>> ob.matrix_world = R @ ob.matrix_world
>>> ob.rotation_euler
Euler((0.5235987901687622, 0.7853982448577881, 1.0471975803375244), 'XYZ')
```

and again

```
>>> ob.matrix_world = R @ ob.matrix_world
>>> ob.rotation_euler
Euler((1.6257474422454834, 0.4853370189666748, 2.580118417739868), 'XYZ')
```

Please note this is global rotation.  For local use `ob.matrix_local` instead.

Note: As pointed out by @lemon for Eulers could also use

```
ob.rotation_euler.rotate(Euler((x, y, z)))
```

to transform  the local euler rotation from another.

For a lot of cases, the axis and angle is defined.  Eg make a 4x4 rotation matrix of 30 degrees around the axis (1, 1, 1)

```
R = Matrix.Rotation(radians(30), 4, (1, 1, 1))
```

Our R from above as an axis / angle rotation

```
>>> R.to_quaternion().to_axis_angle()
(Vector((0.03912381827831268, 0.7727739214897156, 0.6334742903709412)), 1.2104885578155518)
```

is the equivalent of rotating 69.356 degrees around axis (0.03912381827831268, 0.7727739214897156, 0.6334742903709412)